# Get control/access elements out of HTML js object using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to access the  element from a HTML string using JQuery.

I have a following AJAX function which returns HTML text on success. I wish to extract only the contents of the  tag from that HTML text using Jquery.

suppose i have a variable `resp` containing HTML content. I want to access the contents of the  tag inside this HTML content as below..

```
var resp = "<html><head></head><body><form action="changePassword" name="fmChangePassword"> .... form elements .... </form></body> </html>"
alert(resp); //this alerts the full HTML content properly                 
alert($(resp).find("form").html()); //trial 1 -- returns NULL
var test = $(resp).find("#changePassword"); //#changePassword is the ID of the form
//alert(test.html());
displayChangePwdWindow(test);   //need to pass the form content here
```

I tried using `.find()` but no success.

Can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?? will give the full code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: try to alert resp, are you getting the html in that?

Comment: Can you show your resp content? Maybe something is wrong with it. Because that should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/cEBsF/

Comment: Edited the question to make it clearer. Yes, the HTML content is getting alerted properly.

Comment: I suspect some weird characters (encoding) in your resp that dont allow jquery to parse it as html

Comment: use json or xml for this. HTML isnt made for what you want to do. It works, but very hackisch..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be this can help you

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(errorThrown);
   },
   success: function(resp){
      var test = jQuery("<div/>").append(resp).find("#changePassword");
      alert(test.html());
      displayChangePwdWindow(test);  //need to pass the form content here    
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to use `.filter()` instead of `.find()`.
you can check the **Demo**: [first demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cEBsF/2/)

or maybe if you still want to use `.find()` you could place the HTML into a wrapper  to search from.
you can check the **Second Demo**: [second demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cEBsF/4/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML
Create a hidden div in your body....

```
<div id="DIVID" style="display:none"></div>
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {alert(errorThrown);},
        success: function(resp){

         $('#DIVID').html(resp);
         var test = $("#changePassword").html();

         displayChangePwdWindow(test);  //need to pass the form content here    
        }
});
```

OR..
you just append it to a body first.. no need to create a hidden div

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {alert(errorThrown);},
        success: function(resp){

         $(document.body).append(resp);
         var test = $("#changePassword").html();

         displayChangePwdWindow(test);  //need to pass the form content here    
        }
});
```

Comment: looking at the your it looks like you are adding the complete `resp` content (i.e. the full HTML content) into the DIV. I just want the `<form>` content of `resp`

Comment: i am adding the full html content to the div... and using the selector to select the id... $("#changePassword"). which now, will be available in the body... so this should work.....